# Responsive centering an image using css, bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center an image that has a background video container. I would like for it to be exactly centered vertically and horizontally. At the moment i can only center the image horizontally but having trouble centering it vertically. When i do center the image it does'nt become responsive. Any ideas?

This is how it looks on my header area:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vikvx.jpg

HTML code:

```
<div class="header-container">

        <div class="video-container">
            <video preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" volume= "0">

            <source src="video/backgroundAnime.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="video/backgroundAnime.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="video/backgroundAnime.ogv" type="video/ogg">                
            </video>

        </div>

        <img src="img/albayda.png" class="img-responsive center-block">

    </div>
```

CSS code:

```
    .header-container{
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      border-left: none;
      border-right: none;
      position: relative;
      padding: 20px;
     }

    .video-container{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0%;
      left: 0%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
     }

     video{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      width: 100%;
     }

     .img-responsive{
       margin:0 auto;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.header-container img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: That does center it, however when i resize the window for smaller devices the image becomes misplaced so it isnt responsive.

Comment: So is it not shrinking as you reduce the size of the window?

Comment: No it stays the same size and gets misplaced below the header area

Comment: Can you please add max-width: 100% to my previous CSS? Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Strange. Have a look at this pen to see how it should be working, just in case there's a missing property somewhere - http://codepen.io/chrislo2401/pen/rjPxyd

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<img>` tag you may use a `<div>` with centered non-repeating background and then make it fill container with `position:absolue;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0` and optional `pointer-events:none`.